# Empty textbox as NULL in database

Tags: php, mysql, null, string

I have problem with set empty value in UPDATE when textbox is empty. It's my value:

```
$kod = $_POST['Kod'];
$kod = !empty($kod) ? "'$kod'" : "NULL";
```

and query:

```
$query = "UPDATE Sprzety SET Kod = $kod, Wlasciciel = '$wlasciciel', Konfiguracja = '$konfiguracja' WHERE SprzetID = '$id'";
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Well, for one thing you're inviting an SQL injection by using values from the _POST in an SQL statement like that.

Comment: @PaulTomblin What is better method here?

Comment: @cadi2108 Use prepared statements with `mysqli_` or `PDO` functions. `mysql_` functions are being [deprecated](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql).

Comment: @PaulTomblin write in answers, I will mark it as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `mysqli_` or `PDO` functions. Below is a `mysqli_` procedural solution:

```
$kod = !empty($_POST['Kod']) ? $_POST['Kod'] : null;

//$link refers to your mysqli_ connection
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, 
    "UPDATE UPDATE Sprzety 
     SET Kod = ?, Wlasciciel = ?, Konfiguracja = ?
     WHERE SprzetID = ?")) {

/* bind parameters for markers */
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssi", $kod, $wlasciciel, $konfiguracja, $id);

/* execute query */
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```